# Filtering models based off of the concatenation of a field on a one to many relationship in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Say I had some models defined as such:

```
Class Document(models.Model):
    pass

Class Paragraph(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name="paragraphs")
```

And I wanted to find all of the Documents that have the word "foo" contained in any of their paragraphs text fields.

Something like:

```
Document.objects.annotate(text=[Concatenation of all paragraphs text]).filter(text__icontains='foo')
```

How would I go about this in a Django way, not writing direct SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
queryset = Paragraph.objects.filter(text__icontains='foo')

text = ''.join(obj.text for obj in queryset)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ReinstateMonica posted in her answer starting with filtering the Paragraph objects seems like the easiest approach. The result of this could be used to filter the documents. If you only have only one relevant text field the approach could look something like:

```
results = Document.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Paragraph.objects.filter(
        text__icontains='foo').values_list('document', flat=True)
    )
```

If your Paragraph model contains multiple text fields you can first concat the fields and then use the same approach, so:

```
from django.db.models import Concat

qs = Document.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Paragraph.objects.annotate(
        conc_text=Concat('text', 'text2') # all relevant text fields
    ).filter(
        conc_text__icontains='foo'
    ).values_list(
        'document', flat=True
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django ORM can perform [queries that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```py
Document.objects.filter(paragraphs__text__icontains='foo')
```